# exception the type or namespace entityFrameworkModel is missing

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

Hello In my solution I've' got a class library named 'EntityFrameworkModel' AND here i add 
ADO.NET ENTITY DATA MODEL. So my .edmx model perfectly created.

In my other project in this solution - which is asp,net project, in my web form here is what I do

1. I add the reference to my class library with the .edmx model
2. I add the

   ```
   using EntityFrameworkModel  ;directive
   ```
3. I make one really simple function

   ```
   public void LoadTourists()
   {           
       var db = new excursionEntities();

       foreach (var tourist in db.Tourists)
       {
           lblproba.Text += tourist.Name_kir.ToString();  
       }
   }
   ```

which I call on page_Load. 
But I keep getting the above error

Comment: from EntityFrameworkModel ;directive remove directive

Comment: excuse me I didn't understand what to do

Comment: you need to add a reference to EntityFramework.dll and/or System.Data.Entity.dll to you web project

Comment: I add using System.data.Entity but nothing changed